# error when setting the job.setInputFormatClass

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am facing certain error while setting my job for a custom InputFormat

Below Is my Code

```
package com.nline_delimiter;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;



public class NL_driver {

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Configuration conf=new Configuration(true);

    Job job_run =new Job(conf);

    job_run.setJobName("nline input format each line seperate wth delimiter");

    job_run.setJarByClass(NL_driver.class);

    job_run.setMapperClass(NL_mapper.class);
    job_run.setReducerClass(NL_reducer.class);
    job_run.setInputFormatClass(NL_inputformatter.class);;


    job_run.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job_run.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job_run.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job_run.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job_run,new Path("/home/hduser/input_formatter_usage.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job_run, new Path("/home/hduser/input_formatter_usage"));

    job_run.waitForCompletion(true);
}
}
```

The Line

```
job_run.setInputFormatClass(NL_inputformatter.class)
```

shows error

The NL_inputformatter is a custom Inputformatter class that extends the FileInputFormat

Is there something I need to import for the setInputFormatClass, because the default error check in Eclipse asks me to change the setInputFormatClass to setOutFormatClass but doesn't asks for any Import.

The Sourcecode for NL_inputformatter is below.

```
package com.nline_delimiter;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class NL_inputformatter extends FileInputFormat<Text, IntWritable>{

@Override
public RecordReader<Text, IntWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit input,
        JobConf job_run, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("I am Inside the NL_inputformatter class");
    reporter.setStatus(input.toString());
    return new NL_record_reader(job_run, (FileSplit)input);


}

}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shows what error? Please post the compiler error and the NL_inputformatter source code.

Comment: As requested I have adder the source code for the NI_inputformatter....Well the error is --------                                   The method setInputFormatClass(Class<? extends InputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<NL_inputformatter>)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the `FileInputFormat` from the old `Hadoop` API with the new one. You have to change your import and your implementation:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
```

to

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
```

Comment: It's not you having the issue, maybe yours is different... and maybe there's other issue but the error in the comment of Max from April 20 is totally due to the class imported.